# Are there Common Dumbbell and Barbell Diameters?

Tags: weightlifting, exercise-equipment, dumbbells, barbell

I have some basic weights, dumbbells and a barbell.

I've always assumed there were 30mm and 50mm diameters for weights, but when I measured my dumbbells they appear to be 25mm and my barbell is 30mm. Could this be correct, are there some other measurement standards? Which size should I my barbell weights be? Are there any problems with 30mm barbell weights?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shopping/equipment recommendations

Comment: There are too many questions in this question combined, the last paragraph should be removed as that makes the question a shopping question.

Comment: most good barbell-bars are 50mm. (Where good means: can take alot of weight). If you dont need that much weight, it might be unimportant. For dumbbells it doesnt really matter, but it is nice to it in the same size as the barbell, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Most people don't think about making sure their barbells and dumb-bells are the same diameter. Differences in size are common as well as different diameters between barbells and also between dumbbells. There is no "standard" size as such, it's what you prefer. Some Olympic barbells have thicker bars but today you can simply buy bar-grips to fit any diameter bar (Olympic barbells cost an arm and a leg). Go with what works for you.